# Color a Grid by similar column values

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

With Ext GWT 2, how do I color a Grid by similar column values?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to specify the background colour of cells within the grid based on the cell value? You can modify the CSS stlye for each individual cell using GridCellRenderers.

Here I'm defining the background colour via the style property based on the rowIndex to do a crude (and horribly coloured) row-banding colour scheme.

```
  final ColumnConfig colConfig = new ColumnConfig("myProperty", "My Property", 250 );
  colConfig.setRenderer( new GridCellRenderer<MyModelModel >() {

    @Override
    public Object render(
      final MyModelModel model,
      final String property,
      final ColumnData config,
      final int rowIndex,
      final int colIndex,
      final ListStore<MyModelModel> store,
      final Grid<MyModelModel> grid) {

    final String valueToDisplay = "Some Value";

    if( rowIndex % 2 == 0 ) {
      config.style = "background-color: pink;";
    }
    else {
      config.style = "background-color: blue;";
    }

    return valueToDisplay;
    }
  });
```

You can also use the config.css to specify a CSS class name.

Comment: To clarify, it's doing a crude row-banding for only a specific column.